# Does the completeness relation for vector bosons hold also in this form?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, complex-numbers, bosons

Consider a generic Spin-1 vector field (massless) $A^{\mu}$, we know that the solution for its equations of motion can be built as
$$A^{\mu}(x)=∫ d^{3}kN_{k}(\epsilon^{\mu}(\stackrel{\rightarrow}{k},\lambda)\hat{a}_{k,\lambda}e^{-ik\cdot x}+\epsilon^{*\mu}(\stackrel{\rightarrow}{k},\lambda)\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{k,\lambda}e^{ik\cdot x})$$
where $\epsilon^{\mu}(\stackrel{\rightarrow}{k},\lambda)$ are the polarizations of $A^{\mu}$.By construction they satisfy the following completeness relation
$$\sum_{\lambda=0}^{3}g_{\lambda\lambda}\epsilon_{\mu}(\stackrel{\rightarrow}{k},\lambda)\epsilon_{\nu}(\stackrel{\rightarrow}{k},\lambda)=g_{\mu\nu}$$
My question is:- Is it true also for the combination $\sum_{\lambda=0}^{3}g_{\lambda\lambda}\epsilon_{\mu}(\stackrel{\rightarrow}{k},\lambda)\epsilon^{*}_{\nu}(\stackrel{\rightarrow}{k},\lambda)$? The combination with both complex conjugates is obviously true, but I can't find a way to use both relation to prove the validity of that one. Any hints?